# Make a class comparable so that I can get the max paremeter value of class instances within a list (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, class, functools

I have a class that defines a single element (`Request`) and another class (`RequestsBook`) that is comprised from `Request` instances. The `RequestsBook` also has methods to append more requests into the book.

```
class Request:
    def __init__(self, req_id, req_type, value):
        self.req_id = req_id
        self.req_type= req_type
        self.value = value

class RequestsBook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.requests_book = list()

    def add(self, new_req):
        self.requests_book.append(new_req)

    def get_max_value_of_type(self, req_type):
        # pass
```

As seen above, I want to understand how I can **efficiently get the maximum `value` of those `Request` instances inside the `RequestsBook` list that match a specific type**.

For example:

```
rb = RequestsBook()
rb.add(Request(1, 'A', 100))
rb.add(Request(2, 'B', 42))
rb.add(Request(3, 'A', 78))
rb.add(Request(4, 'A', 12))

rb.get_max_value_of_type('A') # should return 190
rb.get_max_value_of_type('B') # should return 42
```

Based on my understanding, I need to make the `Request` class comparable using the [functools.total_ordering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator.

I have never used this decorator before and I am struggling to think of an efficient way to implement `get_max_value_of_type`. Sadly, there are not many online examples for this use case. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you want to make ```Request``` a base class so that ```RequestsBokk``` inherits ```Request``` ie ```class RequestsBook(Request):``` ? Then ```RequestBook``` can refer to what is in ```Request``` ?

Comment: No, `Request` is not a base class of `RequestsBook`. It is just that `RequestsBook` is comprised by `Request` instances.

Comment: You don't have to use the total ordering decorator, that is a convenience. And indeed, you don't have to make your object comparable. Indeed, it isn't clear to me what you are asking, precisely. What do you mean by *efficiently* here? What are the performance characteristics you have in mind?

Comment: Could just sort your list by type and return the last item. Also assigning ```[]``` is more efficient than ```list()```.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good question. By efficient I primarily mean to not perform unescessary passes of the `RequestsBook` list, if possible.

Other than that, I am expirementing with list comprehensions to first extract a sublist of all requests based on the type and find the max on that sublist.

Comment: @InhirCode Could you please give an answer where you demonstrate this "sorting the list by type"? Given that this is a list of objects, how would sorting work without first having defined object comparability?

Comment: No I've run out of time and have to go - check out ```sorted``` function in docs (Python 3.10) with optional argument ```key``` for comparable key.

Comment: @InhirCode why wouldn't you just use `max`? Sorting to find the maximum is unnecessarily inefficient

Comment: So just `max(r.value for r in self.requests_book if r.req_type == req_type)`

Comment: Note all of this is going to work in linear time, the number of passes is usually not a huge concern once you are in that realm. You could achieve better performance by, for example, keeping track of the maximum request when they are added, then it's a constant time retrieval when you ask for it. Of course, this approach would have trade-offs

Comment: @Yannis Have put up code in an answer to demonstrate using ```sorted```. In terms of efficiency, a lot comes down to finding a balance between coding efficiency and processing efficiency which don't always align. ie is this a one off problem to resolve or is it part of something bigger - like database management.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah sure could use ```max``` if you like - ```max``` can use a key function as well if that is wanted. Using ```sorted``` allows for more robust changes if the resulting list is used in other ways. Also ```max``` returns an error if the list is empty whereas ```sorted``` returns an empty list and doesn't break the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sorts by type then sorts by value then retrieves the maximum as the last item. It uses `sorted` builtin with a key function, `attrgetter` from the `operator` module. It follows the explanation in the [Sorting HOWTO tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in Python docs (3.10).

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Request:
    def __init__(self,request=(None,None,None)):
        self.num, self.type, self.value = request

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.num,self.type,self.value))

class RequestsBook(Request):
    def __init__(rb):
        Request.__init__(rb)
        rb.bklist = []
        rb.typetp = ('A','B','C')

    def sortattr(rb,l,a):
        return sorted(l,key=attrgetter(a))

    def maxtype(rb):
        typel = rb.sortattr(rb.bklist,'type')
        maxl = []
        for t in rb.typetp:
            tl = [req for req in typel if req.type == t]
            mtl = rb.sortattr(tl,'value')
            maxl.append(mtl[-1])
        return maxl           
    
inputl = [(1,'A',100),(2,'B',40),(3,'C',30),(4,'A',40),(5,'A',10),(6,'A',80),(7,'C',30),(8,'C',10),(9,'B',70),(10,'B',90)]
bk = RequestsBook()
bk.bklist = [Request(i) for i in inputl]
maxtypel = bk.maxtype()
print('input: ',inputl)
print('output: ',maxtypel)
```